# Can I create a custom "routerLink" in Angular?

Tags: angular

In my Angular application I have 2 different types or URLs. Some that contain an ELEMENT_ID, some that don't have it.

Instead of having to add the ELEMENT_ID on every "routerLink" (I have a lot of them..), I would like to create a custom "routerLink" directive, such as "customRouterLink" that always puts the ELEMENT_ID in front of the parameters given. So for example:

- [customRouterLink]="/questions/ask" will direct to "https://stackoverflow.com/ELEMENT_ID/questions/ask"
- [routerLink]="/questions/ask" will direct to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can see how the routerLink directive is implemented here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts so yes it should be possible to implement your own. However, perhaps using a *ngFor would be simpler?

Comment: check this https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will have a look now. In what way would you use the *ngFor?